# Dime y decime ¿Son intercambiables?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, dialectos, voseo

En las siguientes oraciones que creé yo mismo, ¿el uso de **Dime** y **Decime** tienen el mismo significado? ¿Ambos son correctos?

> No llores así, no quiero verte triste. **Dime** / **Decime** todo lo
> que estás sintiendo y verás cómo te sentirás mejor.
>
> **Dime** / **Decime** lo que piensas de nuestro nuevo proyecto. ¿Crees que tiene alguna posibilidad de éxito?

De acuerdo con la investigación que hice el uso de **dime** es mucho más común, pero también me encontré con un par de frases en las que se utiliza el **decirme**, así que me pregunto si son intercambiables.

Comment: El verbo dimir no existe. El verbo es decir. Dime/decime son formas de conjugarlo . En tus ejemplos las dos formas de conjugarlo son intercambiables y correctas.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo. Lo más extraño es que aunque en el sitio https://dle.rae.es/dimir?m=form esta palabra dimir no aparece como verbo en otros sitios sí aparece e incluso con sus formas de conjugación, como aquí: https: //conjugacao.reverso.net/conjugacao-es Espanhol-verbo-dimir.html
y aquí: https://www.bomespanhol.com.br/conjugar/verbo/dimir Para alguien que está empezando a estudiar español solo, a veces se vuelve muy complicado.

Comment: @Itamar [dimir](https://dle.rae.es/dimir) sí que es un verbo. Pero su significado no tiene nada que ver con "decir", y su uso es muy localizado (Asturias).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Gramaticalmente ambas formas son correctas. Sin embargo, algunas de las personas que aprenden el español como su lengua materna no usan "decime", ni al hablar ni al escribir. En tus dos oraciones, la forma usual en muchos lugares (aunque no en todos)es "dime". En algunas partes, si dices "decime", no te van a entender muy bien.

Comment: Los hablantes nativos? Por favor, busca una palabra adecuada. Los argentinos y los españoles somos nativos: unos de Argentina y otros de España.

Comment: Pues precisamente a eso me refiero. Un hablante nativo es una persona que adquiere una lengua durante su infancia y es capaz de usarla con fluidez a lo largo de toda su vida. Todos aquellos que viven en Argentina, España, Brasil, México... son hablante nativos del español. Existen incluso personas de Inglaterra, Francia, Estados Unidos y otros países de habla inglesa que aprenden el idioma español desde pequeños como si fuera su lengua materna.

Comment: Ok @carlos-beltran , creo entiendo lo que quieres decir pero es incorrecto pues los nativos argentinos o uruguayos, por ejemplo, usan voseo (decime) ; a nivel oral y escrito. Puedes especificar los nativos españoles, si deseas.

Comment: Esta respuesta realmente es absurda. No sabés que en otros países hispanohablantes se habla distinto al tuyo, o creés que por alguna razón esas formas son menos válidas? Ante la duda, no, en Argentina no es normal, ni habitual, ni usual hablar o escribir de tú (y probablemente ocurra igual en otros sitios, pero yo intento no generalizar de lo que no tengo idea).

Comment: @CarlosBeltran esta respuesta generalizaba incorrectamente el término "hablante nativo", excluyendo a los hablantes de regiones como Argentina y Uruguay, donde la forma más común es "decime". A varios usuarios del sitio les ha molestado esta generalización. He editado la respuesta para dejar claro que lo que se dice aquí es aplicable a España (y no necesariamente a todos los hablantes nativos de español). Puedes editar otra vez si tu intención era referirte a otra región (por ejemplo México). Pero por favor, no hagas una edición que vuelva a incluir esa generalización incorrecta.

Comment: @wimi gracias por tu edición. Si embargo, y pese a las aparentes molestias de algunos, el término "hablante nativo" o " nativo hablante" se define como aquella persona que adquiere una lengua (en este caso el español) desde su infancia, y que normalmente se convierte en su instrumento natural de pensamiento y comunicación. Así se usa el término en, por ejemplo M. Colín Rodea, "El acento extranjero como marcador de origen y símbolo de poder
a partir de las diferencias étnicas y psicolingüísticas", Estudios de Lingüística Aplicada, núm. 15/16, 1992.El término "hablante nativo" no es incorrecto.

Comment: @Gaviota Pues quebueno que no intentas generalizar, pues yo tampoco. Yo me atengo a las definiciones precisas de los términos, e intento ayudar a la persona que puso el post de modo que, cuando se comunique con distintas personas, pueda hacerlo de la mejor manera. Yo he hablado con personas de Argentina, Chile, España, México, Guatemala, y con todas ellas la comunicación es perfecta al usar la palabra "dime". Aunque yo no he dicho que "decime" sea incorrecto.

Comment: El problema es que al inicio escribiste que «los hablantes nativos no usamos "decime", ni al hablar ni al escribir», cosa que es incorrecta según tus propias definiciones, ya que l@s habitantes de Argentina o de las otras regiones voseantes son hablantes nativ@s, y no pareces discrepar con esa afirmación. La respuesta actual ya no está estrictamente equivocada, pero todavía es engañosa, puesto que no indica que la primera oración se aplica igualmente a «dime», en la medida en que hay personas que no lo usan en ningún contexto. En fin, parece presentar un dialecto particular como normativo.

Comment: @CarlosBeltran se agradece la buena intención. Pero una respuesta imprecisa o confusa, no es una buena respuesta. Puede generar más problema que solución al lector. No tomes los comentarios como ataques, los usuarios únicamente intentamos mantener la callidad en las respuestas para el bien común.

Answer (score 7):

**Respuesta rápida**

Ambos son correctos. ***Dime*** es el más extendido en América y España. ***Decime*** se usa solo en algunos paises de America del Sur.

**Respuesta detallada**

1.1) **Diferencia?**

*Decime* es un ***voseo***, usado en algunos paises de América, especialmente en *Argentina, Uruguay, Paraguay*. En *España, México, Cuba, Venezuela, etc.* no se usa. Y en otros, como Colombia, se usa el voseo con personas no cercanas (a modo de respeto/reverencial), y se tutea (dime tú) a personas más próximas.

```
La diferencia es el lugar donde su uso es común, pero el significado es el mismo.
```

1.2) **Son intercambiables?**

Depende del lugar donde lo uses. A nivel gramátical son correctos ambos. **Dime (tú)** y **Decime (vos)** son 2ª persona del imperativo del verbo decir.

Pero ten en cuenta que en algunos paises el voseo está extendido a nivel oral y escrito. Lo encontrarás en periódicos, libros, radio y TV. Sin embargo, en otros paises no se usa.

- Si usas "decime" en España/México/Venezuela/..., te entenderán perfectamente y reconoceran que el parlante/escritor usa voseo.
- Si usas "dime" en Argentina, sabrán que hablas un dialecto de un lugar que no vosea.

En estas fuentes podrás encontrar documentación de la RAE sobre el voseo:

- [Voseo verbal](https://www.rae.es/dpd/voseo), en el imperativo. (2.1.2.5. Voseo verbal en el imperativo)
- [Pronombres personales tónicos](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20t%C3%B3nicos)
- [Extensión del Voseo en el mundo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_de_Am%C3%A9rica#/media/Archivo:Voseo-extension-real.PNG)

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en algunos lugares se usan ambos pronombres (en el cotidiano en ciertas zonas de Colombia puedo hablar con vos o puedo hablar con usted, según la confianza que tengamos, al igual que ciertas zonas de Centroamérica o de Ecuador)

Comment: @VeAqui En Argentina, Uruguay o Paraguay también podés hablar de usted, lo que sería raro es hablar de tú ;)